# Post file with curl when field name is something like "image[]"

Tags: php, curl

How can I post a file using curl when in the form the field name has "[]" ? I'm using the @ with the path of the file to be uploaded and this works perfect, but the image I send doesn't show. Help please !!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the brackets. For example:

`curl -XPOST -d@/tmp/image\[\]123.png http://localhost`

Or if you prefer quotes because you'll be doing a lot of this sort of thing:

`curl -XPOST -d@"/tmp/image[]123.png" http://localhost`

Comment: Thanks Sam, but I didn't explain myself well. I want to do this using PHP. Should I escape the brackets in the parameters array as well ?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. It's as easy as treat the image field as an array. For example:

```
$params = array('image[0]'=>$image1,'image[1]'=>$image2,'image[2]'=>$image3)
```

Tested and working !!!